# How do I open open-source projects in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, github, android-studio

I'm very new to Android programming, and I wanted to try learning by example.  I found this open source project on Github: https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_contacts

I was hoping to open this in Android Studio so I could modify certain elements and see the result by running it, eventually learning how the process works as a whole.  The problem is when I download the zip file and try to open the folder inside with Android Studio, nothing shows up.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: May be easier to clone the project from the clone URL using `git clone https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_contacts.git`. Then you should just have to import the project into Android Studio

Answer (score 6):

In Android Studio, close all open projects until you get the "Welcome to Android Studio" screen. Choose "Check out project from Version Control", and in the popup, choose "GitHub".  Screenshot:

[image]

Follow the UI from there.

Answer (score 2):

Try to checkout it directly into Android Studio, VCS->Checkout from version Control->Git

Answer (score 1):

Open all projects using:

> Import project (Eclipse ADT, Gradle, etc)

I usually open my project that is saved in Google Drive in other computer, and the next option never work to me:

> Open an existing Android Studio project

I always use the first option to avoid problems.

Answer (score 0):

Use **Open an existing directory** in Android studio.
Navigate the project you wish to open to the directory containing such folders as:

- manifest
- java/src
- res

  ...etc.

Now, Open.

Answer (score 0):

By default, on Android Studio 2.2.2, when you open an existing Android Studio project, you land on an empty page showing only the name of your project on the top left (just below the open, save, refresh shortcuts icons) but side panels that contains your project structure and details are hidden.

You can open these panels either by pressing "alt + 1" as suggested on the background of the "starting IDE page" or by clicking on menu: "View" -> "Tool Buttons".